# How do I use jQuery to display multiple URLs from a database?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use **get JSON and jQuery** code to search for **multiple URLs in a database field**  then display all URLs hyperlinked and separated. See Red Box in the **Screenshot** below.

**The backend code is:**

```
 $('#jsonData').append('<h3>Community Plans</h3><a href="' + item.community_plan +  '">' + item.community_plan + '</a>');
```

**On the HTML page right now, the URLs appear clumped together with no space and not hyperlinked.** Notice the \:\ separates them. The database server is **internal** so I cannot provide a link, but you can **SEE** what the database field code looks like in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

In the past this **If/Else statement code** worked to search whether the database field has 'http'. **So maybe part 1 - search whether the database field has 'http' then part 2 display them as separate URLs.**

/ /If it DOES have http then hyperlink it. If it does NOT say http, then remove the hyperlink and display plain text//

```
    if (/http/i.test(item.community_plan)) {
        $('#jsonData').append('<h3>Community Plans</h3><a href="' + item.community_plan + '">' + item.community_plan + '</a>');
    }
    else {
        $('#jsonData').append('<h3>Community Plans</h3><p>' + item.community_plan + '</p>');
    }
```

Comment: What's the question? I don't really see a question here. Please post sample json and explain simply what you are attempting to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. If I understand it correctly, you want to parse JSON output by splitting it first, and then checking whether it's a URL.

Here's some pseudocode that might help you along:

```
item.community_plan.split("\\:\\").each(function(url) {
    if(/^http/.test(url) {
        // Starts with http, so should be a 
        $('#jsondata').append('<h3>other links</h3><a href="'+url+'">'+url+'</a>');
    } else {
        $('#jsondata').append('<h3>other links</h3><p>'+url+'</p>');
    }
});
```

You might want to see whether the URL actually starts with http (or https if applicable). The `^` in front of the test takes care of that. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp for more information.

Comment: Yes that is similar to what I'm trying to do. Thank you SO MUCH for replying! Sorry for any confusion. I'm trying to write code that basically says "If the field has multiple urls, then hyperlink each url separately" And yes each one does have http.